# Laravel Restful Api: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I wanted to return some specific data of an Article.

So I made this Api Controller:

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::find(1);
        return new \App\Http\Resources\v1\Article($articles);
    }
}
```

And then created this Resource:

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

```
class Article extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
           'art_title' => $this->art_title,
           'art_description' => $this->art_description
        ];
    }
}
```

So basically every article has a field named `art_title` as Article Title and `art_description` as Article Body.

But when I run this code, I get this error:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) **Trying to get property 'art_title' of
> non-object**

I don't really know what on earth is going wrong here? So if you know, please help me with this cause I've got headache!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly by using `find()` and `new Article()` resource. You are working with a singular object. Therefor going forward would be easier to name it singular to avoid confusion.

```
$article = Article::find(1);
```

Secondly, i believe article 1 is not found, since you are accessing properties on a null object, check if article 1 is there. But going forward, the more correct approach, is to simply fail the code and throw the proper exception.

```
$article = Article::findOrFail(1);
```

Then you will know, when articles are not there.